# Как сделать drag and drop картинки в поле input?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно сделать, чтобы при перетаскивании картинки из локального диска в область `input`, картинка записалась в `value` этого `input`. То есть нужен такой же эффект как при обычном выборе файла картинки.

Искал подобные решение, но максимум что находил так это просто вывод картинки после перетаскивания. **Но** мне нужен не вывод, а именно, чтобы картинка записалась (сохранилась) в `value` `input`'а как при обычном выборе файла.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function readfiles(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('fileDragName').value = files[i].name
    document.getElementById('fileDragSize').value = files[i].size
    document.getElementById('fileDragType').value = files[i].type
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      document.getElementById('fileDragData').value = event.target.result;}
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
  }
}
var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  this.className = '';
  e.preventDefault();
  readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
}
```

```css
#holder.hover { border: 10px dashed #0c0 !important; }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/">
  <input type="file"><input id="fileDragName"><input id="fileDragSize"><input id="fileDragType"><input id="fileDragData">
  <div id="holder" style="width:200px; height:200px; border: 10px dashed #ccc"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый отклик, но это не то что я имел ввиду. Я имел ввиду чтобы само поле `<input type="file">` получило в value картинку также как и при обычном выборе файла